# Probability that a biased 1-d random walk hits a number before another

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, martingales, random-walk

We have a biased 1-dimensional random walk on the number line. Each timestep, with probability $p$ such that $0<p<1$, it increments by $1$, otherwise it decrements by $1$. Given positive integers $a$ and $b$, we want to know the probability of hitting $-a$ before hitting $b$ (when starting at $0$).

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_walk#One-dimensional_random_walk, I know that the result for unbiased random walks (i.e. $p=\frac{1}{2}$) is $\frac{b}{a+b}$. But how to derive for biased random walks?

Comment: This is the classic Gambler's ruin problem, most books/lectures on Markov processes should cover that and the derivation for the probabilities and biased coins.

Comment: @Yannick I don't have access to such books / lectures. Do you happen to have a link to such a lecture / document that derives this?

Comment: Googling "probability of winning gamblers ruin" gives me these lecture notes http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/FE-Notes/4700-07-Notes-GR.pdf. You have to shift your line so that -a is 0 (i.e. ruin probability) and b+a is N (i.e. probability of winning). Try to see whether you can apply this to your problem!